# how to filter laravel api pagination with vuejs

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vue.js

Ok so I am using Laravel's pagination for api resource and it gives me the structure like below :

```
{
   current_page: 1,
   data: [
      {
         some data
      },
      {
         somedata
      }
   ],
   first_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/api/accommodation?page=1",
   from: 1,
   last_page: 3,
   last_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/api/accommodation?page=3",
   next_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/api/accommodation?page=2",
   path: "http://localhost:8000/api/accommodation",
   per_page: 2,
   prev_page_url: null,
   to: 2,
   total: 5
}
```

Now if I want to write a filter for my api to search something in it and I want to search in all api not just the first page how can do it? Should I store all in vuejs or react then filter or is there any way to read all the data or even I should not use the laravel pagination for it as it may cause trouble for frontend?

Comment: Send through the search params to your api and have it filter the results for you.

Comment: Yes @RossWilson but how can i read next page ?? and previous pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you paginate with laravel, it takes all the parameters present in the request. So you have to make this kind of request :

```
http://localhost:8000/api/accommodation?page=1&filter1=blabla&filter2=blabla
```

Then your application will receive the result like this :

```
    {
   current_page: 1,
   data: [
      {
         some data
      },
      {
         somedata
      }
   ],
   first_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/api/accommodation?page=1&filter1=blabla&filter2=blabla",
   from: 1,
   last_page: 3,
   last_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/api/accommodation?page=3&filter1=blabla&filter2=blabla",
   next_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/api/accommodation?page=2&filter1=blabla&filter2=babla",
   path: "http://localhost:8000/api/accommodation",
   per_page: 2,
   prev_page_url: null,
   to: 2,
   total: 5
}
```

BUT, in my opinion, the pagination must be done if you have a lot of rows in your database. If it is not the case, I prefer to make an unique call to my api , which get all the rows, and then filter dynamically on the front side (with js filter for example). Let say about 100 rows.... (but it can also depend of other parameters).

Is it more clear for you ?

Comment: yes my api can have up to 15000 records so pagination is a must for it and thanks for the help it was all clear and acepted thanks :)